# PDF of sum of two uniform random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Prior to my question I would like to say that I have read all relevant questions on this topic on stack exchange and other websites, but I am still struggling understanding geometrically what is going on.

My question:

The PDF of the sum of two uniform random variables $X$ and $Y$, $X+Y=Z$.
The solutions can be found at various places but I am having a difficulty finding the bounds when using the convolution approach.

When I draw $x$ and $y$ I can see that $z$ is between $0$ and $2$, because when you plug in $z=0$ you obtain $y=x$ and the square formed by $x$ and $y$ is not included below the line. Similarly, when you plug in $z=2$ the entire square is below the line.

Here is where I am unable to understand what happens. Why does the probability change at $z=1$ which causes us to split the integral? And how does this form the triangular shape for the density of $Z$? I am unable to understand the interaction between two variables and their probabilities, and for this I am unable to correctly understand the bounds of integration.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ standard uniform $U(0,1)$? If not, you should specify their pdf as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an intuitive idea of the shape of the graph of the PDF of $Z$, try substituting various values for $X$ and $Y$ till you some sort of pattern.
Here is one approach:
Since we know that $X$ and $Y$ are uniform, lets consider 11 values ($\{0,0.1,...,1\}$) for each, and observe how $Z$ behaves.
For $X=0$, $Z = Y$ and you get 11 points ($\{0,0.1,...,1\}$) for $Z$.
For $X=0.1$, $Z = Y + 0.1$ and you get 11 points ($\{0.1,0.2,...,1.1\}$).
.
.
For $X=1$, $Z = Y + 1$ and you get 11 points ($\{1,1.1,...,2\}$).
From this, you can see how the values of $Z$ are.
For $Z = 0$, there is 1 point.
For $Z = 0.1$, there are 2 points.
.
.
For $Z = 0.9$, there are 10 points.
For $Z = 1.0$, there are 11 points.
For $Z = 1.1$, there are 10 points.
.
.
For $Z = 1.9$, there are 2 points.
For $Z = 2$, there is 1 point.

So, you can see that the density increases till $Z= 1$ and decreases after that, thus giving the triangle shape. This is also the reason for splitting the integral.
(For better understanding, try plotting a graph, and adding a point to every value of $Z$ and observing the triangular shape of the graph).

Note that this is just to get an intuition, and not the accurate way of deciding what the PDF of $Z$ is.
For that, you can use convolution to get $$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx$$ For $z<0$ and $z\geq 2$, we will have $f_Z(z) = 0$. From our intuition, we see that it is necessary to break down the integral into two intervals $(0,1]$ and $(1,2)$. Integrating is easy after that, and you get $f_Z(z) = z$ for $z \in (0,1]$, and $f_Z(z) = 2-z$ for $z \in (1,2)$.

Hope this is what you had asked for!

Answer (score 1):

Think of the joint pdf being a cheese-cube flushed against axes in the first octant. Now, imagine the line $y = z- x$ being a long blade cutting the cheese-cube from the top. The part of cheese-cube cut off by the blade on the bottom-left corner is the CDF of $X+Y$. For $z < 1$, the part of cheese-cube cut off by the blade on the bottom-left corner is a triangular prism. For $z > 1$, the shape is different (in this case, it is the cube with a triangular prism taken out). Hopefully, this helps you see why the integral needs to be split at $z=1$.